# Cannot access Windows shares via samba

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I'm trying to follow this guide to access Samba shares: [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin: File sharing with Samba.](http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-file-sharing-with-samba)

but I'm sure there are many of them. I've had problems with Samba before. In fact in my xx years of life on Linux I have never successfully setup Samba.

The steps would be:

1. Update your system
2. Install samba

   ```
    $ sudo apt-get install samba samba-common winbind
   ```
3. Configure windbind

   ```
    $ sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
   ```

   and "wins" to the hosts line.
4. Reboot
5. "Having done this you should now be able to select ‘GO > Network’ from the desktop menu and view your entire Windows and Linux based network."

But in my case I just see "Windows network" which is an empty folder and that's all. No shares from windows neither Linux PC's.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if you still need help but i had the same problem a couple of days ago and asked here. If you want to read my solution have a look at my answer there. I found a solution by myself ;)
[filesystems - Mount linux mount in windows (without ftp)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198545/mount-linux-mount-in-windows-without-ftp)

Comment: [Those instructions](http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-file-sharing-with-samba) concern mainly setting up Samba to make parts of the Linux filesystem accessible over the network using the SMB protocol. The ability to browse and access Windows shares is just briefly mentioned as a side effect, but it seems *that* is what you are trying to achieve. You would need the `cifs.utils`/`smbfs` packages and possibly some desktop environment component: a SMB gvfs backend for Gnome or a SMB kioslave for KDE, for example. Or something like `smbnetfs`.

Comment: Also, after the WannaCry ransomware epidemic of 2017, Microsoft accelerated the deprecation of SMBv1 and associated NetBIOS functionality, so the advice to use `winbind` for `wins` hostname resolution is rapidly becoming obsolete (unless you explicitly enable SMBv1 on the Windows side, which is **very much not recommended** for security reasons). The `cifs.utils` and similar tools will still work for connecting to known Windows shares, but any tools to find and list SMB shares will need to be re-implemented to use the WS-Discover protocol when SMBv1 will no longer be supported by Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samba shares not visible in Network Neighborhood / Windows Explorer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665872/samba-shares-not-visible-in-network-neighborhood-windows-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

If using Ubuntu 12.04 make sure you have the 'smbfs' package installed, anything after that it changed to 'cifs.utils'.

```
$ sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install cifs.utils
```

After a reboot they should show up, although you may have to manually go to them with the smb command in the file explorer window.

```
smb://(servername)/"share"
```

Comment: tried both.. in fact cifs.utils was already installed. no success.