# Mount linux mount in windows (without ftp)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, windows, remote

I successfully mounted my external hard drive (ntfs) to `/mnt/seagate`. I'm using debian and the server is connected over LAN to my PC. So how can I mount my hard drive in my windows explorer without using `ftp`?

**$ nano /etc/fstab:**

```
[..]
# Seagate
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/seagate ntfs defaults 0 2

# Medion
/dev/sdc1 /mnt/medion ntfs defaults 0 2
```

Comment: at the same time or one at a time?

Comment: Is that important? I would say once. My seagate will be auto mounted on boot. I'm not sure if that was the needed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) Download and install Samba:**

```
apt-get install samba samba-common
```

**2) Backup samba.conf:**

```
cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.bak
```

**3) Edit samba.conf:**

```
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Replace all with and edit it to your wishes:

```
[global]
        workgroup = arbeitsgruppe
        server string = %h server (Samba %v)
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        encrypt passwords = true
        invalid users = root
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY
        security = user
        unix extensions = yes

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        browseable = no
        valid users = %S
        writable = yes
        create mode = 0600
        directory mode = 0700
```

**4) Create a samba user:**

```
adduser --disabled-login --shell /bin/false --home <home path - ex. /mnt/seagate> <username>
```

Add user to samba:

```
smbpasswd -a <username>
```

**5) Restart samba:**

```
service samba restart or /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

**6) Add samba to windows:**
Pictured description will be found on [this site](http://blog.thetutorial.de/?p=923) (german).

Briefly: Add `\\<local or external ip>\<username>` to your windows file explorer.

**IMPORTANT:**
You can't mount two same devices with different shares in windows file explorer. For example:

```
\\192.168.1.35\<username1 or share1> and \\192.168.1.35\<username2 or share2>
```

If you add `share2` the windows explorer thinks that there's already a connection (`via share1`), but you think the username or password on the samba-server is wrong. No it's a windows-client problem!

**To solve it,** you need to use `netbios alias`.
For example:

```
[global]
        [..]
        netbios aliases = alias1 alias2 alias3
        [..]
```

So use this:

```
\\alias1\<username1 or share1> and \\alias\<username2 or share2>
```

instead of this:

```
\\192.168.1.35\<username1 or share1> and \\192.168.1.35\<username2 or share2>
```

**Commands:**

```
$ testparm                Test samba configuration
$ pdbedit -L             Show all vaild samba users
$ pdbedit -x -u <user>   Remove user
$ smbpasswd -a <user>       Add user to vaild samba users / Give password
$ smbpasswd -d <user>       Remove user from vaild samba users
$ service samba restart  Restart samba
```

Comment: @Mat I already updated my answer ;) You should have a look!