# Samba shares not visible in Network Neighborhood / Windows Explorer

Tags: ubuntu, windows, samba

Problem:

One can access the share by typing in \server_name or the full path \server_name\path. Yet when browsing through Windows Explorer, the server doesn't show up.

Solution (see answer)

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by that Windows 10 hosts now uses the Windows Service Discovery (runs by default on Windows as a service). I have found that Debian based Samba doesn't use WSD (still uses the good old Browser service). To install the WSD for Debian/Ubuntu follow these steps:

`sudo -i` Interactive Root

`wget https://github.com/christgau/wsdd/archive/master.zip` unpack zip file

`mv wsdd-master/src/wsdd.py wsdd-master/src/wsdd` copy python script

`cp wsdd-master/src/wsdd /usr/bin` copy bins

`cp wsdd-master/etc/systemd/wsdd.service /etc/systemd/system` move the WSDD service

`nano /etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service` and add/modify

- #User=nobody
- #Group=nobody

`systemctl daemon-reload` Reloads the service file

`systemctl start wsdd` Start the service

`systemctl enable wsdd` Enable at boot

Updates:

- I again had issues with the Network Neighbourhood, after I enabled VLANS. As the advertisements of hosts happens over multicast, do ensure that your IGMP snooping is off (or check that it isn't blocking).
- Nowadays one can install WSDD simply with 'apt install wsdd'